# JPQL query convert to SQL query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, jpql

Is it possible to convert JPQL query to SQL and save this query to database?

I want to write JPQL queries when developing program. But whet will deploy application to server I need compile querys to native SQL depends on DB.

Comment: What do you mean to `save` the query in the database ? You have a table with queries or ... ?

Comment: I don't get you. Hibernate does that for you: you execute a JPQL query, and it translates it to SQL and executes it. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes i need save query in database in table for queries.

Comment: I knowabout hibernate but for some reasons i need native SQL

Comment: What is your JPA implementation ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer for Hibernate HQL queries;

```
final Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

final QueryTranslatorFactory ast = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
final QueryTranslatorImpl newQueryTranslator = (QueryTranslatorImpl) ast.createQueryTranslator(queryId, query.getQueryString(), Collections.EMPTY_MAP, (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory);
newQueryTranslator.compile(null, false);
sql = newQueryTranslator.getSQLString();
```

Thanks to:

http://good-old-mushroom-called-bedla.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-convert-hql-to-sql-in-hibernate.html

Comment: This feature should will be added to new version of JPA spec.

Comment: @oleksandr-samsonov How to do it for JPQL using Spring Data JPA ?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no JPA standard way to get the SQL.  The EclipseLink specific solution is available in EclipseLink's FAQ http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_get_the_SQL_for_a_Query.3F